# Opposite of set.intersection in python?

Tags: python, set

In Python you can use `a.intersection(b)` to find the items common to both sets.

Is there a way to do the *disjoint* opposite version of this? Items that are not common to both `a` and `b`; the unique items in `a` unioned with the unique items in `b`?

Answer (score 202, accepted):

You are looking for the *symmetric difference*; all elements that appear only in set a or in set b, but not both:

```
a.symmetric_difference(b)
```

From the [`set.symmetric_difference()` method documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.symmetric_difference):

> Return a new set with elements in either the set or *other* but not both.

You can use the `^` operator too, if both `a` and `b` are sets:

```
a ^ b
```

while `set.symmetric_difference()` takes any iterable for the *other* argument.

The output is the equivalent of `(a | b) - (a & b)`, the union of both sets minus the intersection of both sets.

Producing the output takes O(M+N) time for sets of length M and N, respectively; M steps to copy set `a` then N steps to alter that set based on each value in `b`:

```
def symmetric_difference(a, b):
    result = set(a)
    for elem in b:
        try:
            result.remove(elem)
        except KeyError:
            result.add(elem)
    return result
```

There are in-place variants too, where set `a` is altered directly; use [`a.symmetric_difference_update(b)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.symmetric_difference_update) or `a ^= b`. The in-place variant takes O(N) time, so it depends on the size of set `b` only:

```
def symmetric_difference_update(a, b):
    for elem in b:
        try:
            a.remove(elem)
        except KeyError:
            a.add(elem)
    # no return, a has been updated in-place
```

Comment: Isn't ^ normaly XOR operator?

Comment: @user4847061: it is, but sets have overloaded several such operators. `|` and `&` are normally bitwise OR and bitwise AND, but on sets they give you the union and the intersection. The comparison operators `<`, `<=`, `>` and `>=` have been overloaded too.

Answer (score 7):

```
a={1,2,4,5,6}
b={5,6,4,9}
c=(a^b)&b
print(c) # you got {9}
```

Comment: Why did you add an intersection operation here? This is not the inverse of the intersection, it is the (asymmetric) difference between `b` and `a`. This could have been expressed as `b - a` instead, a far simpler expression! The symmetric difference and true inverse of the intersection of an and b is `{1, 2, 9}` and you had that with `a ^ b`.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is a list comprehension.

```
a = [ 1,2,3,4]
b = [ 8,7,9,2,1]
c = [ element for element in a if element not in b] 
d = [ element for element in b if element not in a] 
print(c) 
# output is [ 3,4]
print(d) 
# output is  [8,7,9]
```

You can join both lists

Comment: The performance on a list comprehension, when compared to a set for the above operations, is MUCH slower. It's okay for small lists, but for large operations, it can take hours and days.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out i didn't knew about it as my  lists are not  usually long ones.

Comment: The question asked about **sets**, not lists. There is a reason for that: the symmetric difference can be produced in O(M+N) time, where M and N are the lengths of the two sets. Your loops take O(MxN) time, for lengths M and N. Try using this with lists length 100 and 1000, then grow this lists by a factor of 10 and try again. Now compare how long it takes if you started with sets.

Comment: Note that you also produce two separate (asymmetric) difference results; that’s not quite the inverse of the intersection. You’d need to join the two lists for that.

Comment: If you **must** have a list then at least convert the longer list to a set first, loop over the shorter list and select all the elements missing from that set while adding those that are not missing to a second set. Then loop over the longer list and select all those elements that are missing in the second set to the output. That’s also an O(N+M) operation.

Answer (score -1):

## e, f are two list you want to check disjoint

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [8,7,9,2,1]

c = []
def loop_to_check(e,f):
    for i in range(len(e)):
        if e[i] not in f:
            c.append(e[i])


loop_to_check(a,b)
loop_to_check(b,a)
print(c)

## output is [3,4,8,7,9]
```

This loops around to list and returns the disjoint list

Comment: This has terrible performance because `value in list` has to check every element in the list for equality; for inputs of length N and M this will take O(MxN) time. The set operation on the other hand only take O(M+N) time where K is the shortest length of the two sets. Try using this on two lists with 1000 elements. Try again with 10000 elements. The question asked about *sets* for a reason.

Answer (score -2):

Try this code for (set(a) - intersection(a&b))

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
b = [2,3]

for i in b:
   if i in a:
      a.remove(i)

print(a)
```

the output is `[1,4,5,6]`
I hope, it will work

Comment: It's usually bad to mutate lists you are iterating over (in this case, there is no real consequence, unless I only care about returning a new list and not modifying `a`). Also `check = i in a` is redundant since you can always `if i in a:`

Comment: @cowbert thanks for your advise. I have fixed it. I will learn more about that.

Comment: You can try with this one-liner solution `print(sorted(set(a)-set(b)))`

Comment: I believer that is called the **relative complement** or **difference** of two sets.

Comment: using numpy this case become easier np.setdiff1d(a, b)

Comment: The question asks about sets, not lists, and this produces the (asymmetric) difference between an and b. That’s not the inverse of the intersection, that’s a *symmetric* difference, so the union of `a - b` and `b - a`.  Try adding `7` to `b` here, it would be included in a symmetric difference.