# Get complement of three lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have three lists:

`a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = [2, 3, 4, 5]
c = [3, 4, 5, 6]`

My goal is to get all values which are not present in all of the three lists: `[1,2,5,6]`
Basically I am searching the "negation" of `set(a) & set(b) & set(c)`.

An efficient solution would be appreciated since the lists are very long.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Opposite of set.intersection in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29947844/opposite-of-set-intersection-in-python)

Comment: @Chris_Rands this is not really a duplicate. One can not easily use the `set.symmetric_difference` method with three sets

Comment: @kalehmann The accepted answer say "The output is the equivalent of (a | b) - (a & b), the union of both sets minus the intersection of both sets."-- it is a clear dupe i think- add your answer to the duplicate if you want

Comment: @Chris_Rands: I will keep my answer because I also added the numpy example for faster computation, but link to your comment and the original question

Comment: @NickA this does not work. `a ^ b` is `{1, 5}`.  The difference to c contains now also a 4

Comment: No problem, this was also my first idea :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The opposite of `set(a) & set(b) & set(c)` is already explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29947844/opposite-of-set-intersection-in-python) as stated by [Chris_Rands](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6260170/chris-rands) in the comments:

```
>>> (set(a) | set(b) | set(c)) - (set(a) & set(b) & set(c))
{1, 2, 5, 6}
```

For really long lists, using numpy should be may efficient:

```
import numpy as np
from functools import reduce

a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = [2, 3, 4, 5]
c = [3, 4, 5, 6]

union = reduce(numpy.union1d, (a,b,c))
intersect = reduce(numpy.intersect1d, (a,b,c))
print(numpy.setdiff1d(union, intersect))
```

Output:

```
[1 2 5 6]
```